# Javascript function like keyIsPressed - using for modifying link href

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events

I need to inspect if a key (f.e. "A") is right now pressed. I found only solutions based on keyup & keydown events, and the programmer must remeber what was fired last time. Example:

```
<a href="any"
  onclick="this.href=keyPressed(65)?varLinkA:varLinkOther;"
  target="_blank">Link text
</a>
```

.

```
pressedKeyList=new Array();

$('body').keydown(
function (event){
    pressedKeyList[event.keyCode]=true;
}
);
$('body').keyup(
function (event){
    pressedKeyList[event.keyCode]=false;
}
);

function keyPressed(cc){
    return pressedKeyList[cc]?true:false;
}
```

This example works fine (in Firefox & IE), but not if **target="_blank"**. In this case keyup event is not fired. The parent window may wait forever. Next time you will open link varLinkA even if the "A" key is not down.

Comment: i wonder, if you say onclick, how can you track keyCode?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 makes a good point. You are checking which key is pressed when a click event occurs for the anchor element. How is a key pressed then?

Comment: Not "which key is pressed" but "which key was pressed before". As you can see, I am calling my own function "keyPressed(keyCode)" that returns true/false value from array "pressedKeyList", depending on previously catched event keyup or keydown.